# Optimizing SOQL Rows

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two VF pages(one for Contact list and one for Account list) having common custom controller. when i open one page(for ex Accounts page), it was retrieving Contact list also, which is leading to cross salesforce limits. Is there is a way to optimize it i.e. when i open Accounts VF page the controller should get only Accounts list but not Contacts and vice versa.

Comment: Use URL parameter to identify the page and based on that execute the query. Better if you can post the code

Comment: Is it only the way?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do your queries in your constructor. I think that is what you may be doing.

Have two separate methods. One for getting your contacts and other for your accounts. Assume that they are named `fetchContacts()` and `fetchAccount()`

Then in your respective pages:

**Contact VF page**

```
<apex:page controller="customController" action="{!fetchContacts}">

</apex:page>
```

**Account VF page**

```
<apex:page controller="customController" action="{!fetchAccounts">

</apex:page>
```

Apart from this, it will also do you good in the long term to restrict the number of rows returned. Perhaps limit to a 100 results, and then provide the user filters to narrow down on the required records.

Another option is to go for Pagination or use OFFSET clause in your queries.

One of the ways to paginate is given in the following example, which I have tried long time back. Modify it as per your requirement.

**VF Page**

```
   <apex:page controller="PagingController">
      <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Paging through Categories of Stuff">

          <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageMessages />

          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Category Results -  Page #{!pageNumber}" columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account}" var="c">
              <apex:column value="{!c.Name}" headerValue="Name"/>
              <apex:column ><apex:inputField value="{!c.Name}"/></apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
          <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveRecords}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:panelGrid columns="4">
        <apex:commandLink action="{!first}">First</apex:commandlink>
        <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" rendered="{!hasPrevious}">Previous</apex:commandlink>
        <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" rendered="{!hasNext}">Next</apex:commandlink>
        <apex:commandLink action="{!last}">Last</apex:commandlink>
        </apex:panelGrid>     
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class PagingController {

    List<Account> account {get;set;}

    // instantiate the StandardSetController from a query locator
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController con {
        get {
            if(con == null) {
                con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id, Name FROM Account Order By Name]));
                // sets the number of records in each page set
                con.setPageSize(15);
            }
            return con;
        }
        set;
    }

    // returns a list of wrapper objects for the sObjects in the current page set
    public List<Account> getAccount() {
        account = con.getRecords();
        return account;
    }

    // indicates whether there are more records after the current page set.
    public Boolean hasNext {
        get {
            return con.getHasNext();
        }
        set;
    }

    // indicates whether there are more records before the current page set.
    public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get {
            return con.getHasPrevious();
        }
        set;
    }

    // returns the page number of the current page set
    public Integer pageNumber {
        get {
            return con.getPageNumber();
        }
        set;
    }

    // returns the first page of records
    public void first() {
        con.first();
    }

    // returns the last page of records
    public void last() {
        con.last();
    }

    // returns the previous page of records
    public void previous() {
        con.previous();
    }

    // returns the next page of records
    public void next() {
        con.next();
    }

    // returns the PageReference of the original page, if known, or the home page.
    public void cancel() {
        con.cancel();
    }

    public void SaveRecords(){
        update account;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have given a good idea. But, my organization have 75000 records. How can i handle this situation?

Comment: You can not show that much data on a visualforce page. You need to employ one of the pagination methods available.

Comment: Added code to the answer, on one way to do pagination.

Comment: Sorry Aslam. I know pagination. But it is not my requirement.

Comment: So you want to show all the 75000 records to the user on one page?

Comment: Yes, Aslam. Is there any suggestible way

Comment: Nope. Not possible without pagination. Not just salesforce, but for any web application showing up so many records on the page is not a good idea.

Comment: Hi Aslam, Do you have any examples in pagination with numbers(i.e. based on page size, page numbers must be altered) for ex. if total size 20 and page size is 10 two page numbers with 1 and 2 must be displayed.

Comment: You can look into jQuery Datatable for that. Gives you a lot of options and works well on VF pages.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite possible. When you call the VF page kindly pass a parameter in URL like :

https://cs13.salesforce.com/apex/yourpagename?object=Account
https://cs13.salesforce.com/apex/yourpagename?object=Contact

Then retrieve this parameter in Constructor in the controller like :

```
String objectName= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('object');
if(objectName == 'Account'){
   //Account Query Here
}
if(objectName == 'Contact'){
   //Contact Query Here
}
```